I use C# version 7.3 and now I want to use double result = operation switch in this version and these versions throw an error - what I do?
I use C# version 7.3 and I want to use double result = operation switch in this version, and my code throws an error - what I do?
The error is thrown on switch statement.
Can anyone help me? I'll be very thankful...
// Function for handling the arithmetic operations.

void PerformArithmetic(string operation)
{
    double num1, num2;

    Console.Write("Enter the first number: ");

    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1))
    {
        Console.Write("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number: ");
    }

    Console.Write("Enter the second number: ");

    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num2))
    {
        Console.Write("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number: ");
    }

    double result = operation switch
    {
        "Addition" => num1 + num2,
        "Subtraction" => num1 - num2,
        "Multiplication" => num1 * num2,
        "Division" => num2 != 0 ? num1 / num2 : double.NaN,
         => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown operation")
    };

    if (operation == "Division" && num2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Division by zero is not allowed.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Result of{operation}: {result}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to return to the calculation menu.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}


Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get.

Well switch expressions have not been introduced in C# 7.3, so you cannot do that. How about using a switch statement?

"I use C# version 7.3" why?

You can use the newest C# version (C# 13.0 as I am writing this), even together with older .NET Core and .NET Framework versions. All you need is a <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> entry in a property group of your *.csproj file. Many newer language features will be available, except those requiring support by  newer CLR or library versions. But the compiler will tell you and there is no danger of using something which could cause problems.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes are you 100% sure that's the case? MS doesn't seem to be that sure last time I checked the docs about using older versions (no official support etc)

I am doing this all the time and I never encountered a problem. There are even NuGet packages supplying missing types to allow, e.g., using the Index and Ranges feature, which would otherwise require a newer BCL version.

Switch expressions don't exist until C# 8, so: either update your compiler version (which is quite significantly out-of-date - from May 2018) or use a different syntax. For example, a switch statement:
double result;
switch (operation)
{
    case "Addition":
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    // ... etc
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown operation");
}

